# How to call a function (with parameters) onClick with React without hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

```
import Gameplay from "./gameplay";

function Grid() {
  const rows = 8;
  const cols = 6;
  const grid = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    const currentRow = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      const ID = col + row * 6 + 1;
      currentRow.push(
        <span
          key={`${row}-${col}`}
          className="cell"
          onClick={() => Gameplay({ ID })}
        >
          {ID}
        </span>
      );
    }
    grid.push(
      <div key={row} className="row">
        {currentRow}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div className="grid">{grid}</div>;
}
```

I have a grid of squares, where I want clicking each square to trigger the function Gameplay. Gameplay takes in the parameter ID, so I can't just do `onClick = {Gameplay}`. However, whenever I do anything else, like `onClick={() => Gameplay({ ID })}`, I get the following error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Is there a way for me to trigger the Gameplay function upon clicking a square?

I have tried `onClick={() => Gameplay({ ID })}` which resulted in `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` I have also tried `onClick={(ID) => Gameplay}` which just doesn't do anything (nothing is triggered when I click, and the console also prints nothing). I've also tried `onClick={Gameplay(ID)}` but that results in an object, since it's not calling a function but the result of the function.

Comment: What's the definition of `Gameplay`? Does it call hooks?

Comment: It does use State: function Gameplay(ID, props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(text);
    setText("");
    if (Solutions(submitted, Clues(ID))) {
      console.log("Correct!");
    }
  }

Comment: `Gameplay` appears to be a React component. We don't invoke React functions directly, we pass them to React ***as JSX*** and React calls the function to render its content when React needs to. When and where do you want this `Gameplay` component to render? What is the UI/UX you are trying to accomplish here? Please [edit] to clarify and provide better details and a more complete [mcve] that includes all the relevant code you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

Bad request on onclick

You need to update onclick function like this

onClick={() => {Gameplay({ ID })}}

Comment: She has already said that she tried using `onClick={() => Gameplay({ ID })}` which resulted in `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Answer (score -1):

I think you are calling `Gameplay` as if it is a normal function, but it is actually a React component, that's what causing this error. If you want to render the `Gameplay` component onclick, you can use `ReactDOM.render()` method.

Here is an example

```
      currentRow.push(
        <span
          key={`${row}-${col}`}
          className="cell"
          onClick={() =>
            ReactDOM.render(
              <Gameplay ID={ID} />,
              document.getElementById("root")
            )
          }
        >
          ID : {ID}
          {", "}
        </span>
      );
```

Here is the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hermann-5ckoq9?file=/src/Grid.jsx:309-632). Try clicking on any ID in the output and it will render the Gameplay component with that ID.